# For what real values of c are the vectors (1-c,1+c) and (1+c,1-c) linearly independent?

Tags: linear-algebra

I know that for the vectors to be linearly independent the scalars can only have one solution which is zero. I can't come up with a way to set this up to come up with all possible values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two vectors can be written
$$
v_1=(1-c,1+c)=(1,1)+c(-1,1)\\
v_2=(1+c,1-c)=(1,1)-c(-1,1)
$$
Consider a linear combination
$$
\alpha v_1+\beta v_2=(\alpha+\beta)(1,1)+c(\alpha-\beta)(-1,1)=0
$$
Since $(1,1)$ and $(-1,1)$ are linearly independent (see below), this means
$$
\begin{cases}
\alpha+\beta=0\\
c(\alpha-\beta)=0
\end{cases}
$$
that implies $2c\alpha=0$. If $c=0$ there are infinitely many solutions, so the vectors are not linearly independent (actually they're the same vector). If $c\ne0$ the equation implies $\alpha=0$ and so $\beta=0$. Thus the vectors are linearly independent.

Why are $(1,1)$ and $(-1,1)$ linearly independent? From $\alpha(1,1)+\beta(-1,1)=(0,0)$ we get
$$
\begin{cases}
\alpha-\beta=0\\
\alpha+\beta=0
\end{cases}
$$
that has only the solution $\alpha=\beta=0$.

---

Second method, with the determinant:
$$
\det\begin{bmatrix}
1-c & 1+c\\
1+c & 1-c
\end{bmatrix}
=(1-c)^2-(1+c)^2=-4c
$$
which is different from $0$ if and only if $c\ne0$.

Answer (score 1):

When is the system
$$\begin{align*}
\lambda (1-c) + \mu (1+c) & = 0\\
\lambda (1+c) + \mu (1-c) & = 0
\end{align*}$$
Uniquely solvable with solution $\lambda,\mu = 0$?

Answer (score 0):

They are linearly independent for all real except zero.